# Create Azure Network Security Group - Retrofit Error

Tags: azure, retrofit2, okhttp, azure-api-apps, azure-sdk

I'm using the Azure Java SDK version 1.15.1. Since I need to connect to Azure using a non-default Java TrustStore, I created my own, custom trust store file which I'm loading into a TrustManager and then create an OkHttpClient.Builder like this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
```

Then I'm creating a Retrofit Builder and use all of that to create my Azure connection object:

```
retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder(); 
retrofitBuilder.baseUrl("https://management.azure.com"); 

com.microsoft.rest.RestClient restClient = new RestClient.Builder(httpClientBuilder, retrofitBuilder) 
    .withCredentials(credentials) 
    .withBaseUrl("https://management.azure.com") 
    .withResponseBuilderFactory(new ServiceResponseBuilder.Factory()) 
    .withSerializerAdapter(new JacksonAdapter())
    .build(); 

Azure azureConnection = Azure.authenticate(restClient, tenantId).withSubscription(subscription);
```

This works fine for retrieving all kinds of data from Azure (networks, security groups, etc.).

But if I want to use this connection to create a new security group:

```
newSecGroup = azureConnection.getAzureConnection().networkSecurityGroups() 
    .define(groupName) 
    .withRegion(regionName) 
    .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName) 
    .withTag("MyCustomTag", groupName) 
    .create();
```

it throws the following exception which doesn't really help me to track down the root cause - maybe someone can point me into the right direction?
Thanks
Kurt

```
Error when trying to create a new Security Group within resource groupksembatest, region eastus with name Cloud__Web Server for policy Web Server: com.microsoft.azure.CloudException
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:740)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$100(AzureClient.java:33)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:160)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:157)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:81)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:27)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:39)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:27)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.DeferredScalarSubscriber.subscribeTo(DeferredScalarSubscriber.java:153)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:32)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:22)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out that it was possible to enable debug logging on the RestClient

```
com.microsoft.rest.RestClient restClient = new RestClient.Builder(httpClientBuilder, retrofitBuilder)
            .withCredentials(credentials)
            .withBaseUrl("https://management.azure.com")
            .withResponseBuilderFactory(new ServiceResponseBuilder.Factory())
            .withSerializerAdapter(new JacksonAdapter())
            .withLogLevel(com.microsoft.rest.LogLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
            .build();
```

it was easy to find and solve my problem. It was simply the fact that I had an empty space in the name of the Network Security Group that I wanted to create and that was not allowed by Azure. 
The HTTP response was MUCH clearer than the "CloudException" I got from the java API error trace.